# default sharedpreferences wont share between activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am trying to pass a string set between activities by sharedpreferences but it seems that the default sharedpreferences made two files for each activity.

i tried to share it with `PRIVATE_MODE` with the same name and it didnt work

```
  SharedPreferences appPrefernces = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        SharedPreferences.Editor appEditor = appPrefernces.edit();
        Set<String> usersSet = appPrefernces.getStringSet("users", new HashSet<String>());
        if(!usersSet.contains(id)) {
            usersSet.add(id);
            appEditor.putStringSet("users", usersSet);
            appEditor.apply();
        }


 SharedPreferences appPrefernces = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Main.this);
                users = appPrefernces.getStringSet("users",new HashSet<String>());
```

it seems that it saved the info but while extracting it i get a get just a partial set

Comment: use `intent.putExtra()` to share strings between activities

Answer (score 1):

In this way you are sure what preferences file you are using:

```
private static void saveUsers(Context context, Set<String> usersSet) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putStringSet("users", userSet).apply();
}

private static Set<String> loadUsers(Context context){
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getStringSet("users", new HashSet<String>());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Andrea_Ebano it seems to work untill i close the app after i enter again it seems to open another sharedpreferences file !!!

Comment: maybe you override it somewhere, post the part of code where you save and load preferences

Comment: `    private void saveUsers() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("preferences", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Set<String> usersSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("users", new HashSet<String>());
        if(!usersSet.contains(id)) {
            usersSet.add(id);
            editor.putStringSet("users", usersSet).apply();
        }
    }`

Comment: this is the save and the then the load 

`    private Set<String> loadUsers(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getStringSet("users", new HashSet<String>());
    }`

Comment: what type is "id"? String?

Comment: You know that in this way you save only when a new element will be add? if you remove element, preferences will not be update

Comment: yes "id" is a string , yeah i know i covered that in a button , but the point is that if i start the app it works fine and it save and load from the same preferences **BUT** when i restart the app it seems that it access to another preferences file and get me just one element of the list !! which driving me crazy for 2 days and the funny thing is that there is another preferences that doing the job just fine

Comment: try editor.clear() before editor.putStringSet("users", usersSet).apply()